# Drupal - Render a sub view/partial within template

Tags: php, drupal, view, themes

How can I create a html snippet that I can reuse across multiple template pages and can pass variable s into? Some like this (but obviously a bit more complicated):

```
<ul>
    <? foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <li><?=$item?></li>
    <? endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) in a custom module, then call the [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) method from within your template.

In your module:

```
mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_theme_name' => array(
      'template' => 'my_template_file_name', // without the .tpl.php extension
      'variables' => array(), // to define default values for passed variables
     )
  );
}
```

In your template:

```
theme('my_theme_name', array('arg1' => 'val1', 'arg2' => 'val2'));
```