# 'Smart' way to include the same HTML in multiple TPL files?

Tags: drupal-theming

Im using the same HTML (below) in multiple views TPL files. Its used to make my own custom pager work with JavaScript.

At the moment im creating a TPL file for each view and then adding the full markup every time. This isnt great from a maintenance point of view as if I need to alter the HTML I will need to do so for every instance.

Is there a 'smarter' way to do this? For instance can I create a new TPL file to house this HTML and call the file in each views TPL file when I need it?

```
  <div class="picThumb">
    <div class="picThumb-inner">
      <div class="picThumb-trig picThumb-trigLeft">Previous</div>
      <div class="picThumb-trig picThumb-trigP1">1</div>
      <div class="picThumb-trig picThumb-trigP2">2</div>
      <div class="picThumb-trig picThumb-trigRight">Next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: No idea, whether this is going in the right direction but if i got you right, you want to use something like snippets: https://www.drupal.org/node/1288700

Comment: Its more an HTML snippet than a PHP one. Is there a way to create new TPL files?

Answer (score 3):

The best option here — is to register a custom template via [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function THEME_OR_MODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom_template'  => array(
      'template' => 'custom-template',
      'variables' => array(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then put your custom HTML in the `custom-template.tpl.php` file.

Then you can "include" it anywhere using [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme) function:

```
<?php print theme('custom_template') ?>
```

Comment: This isnt working for me. Ive changed THEME_OR_MODULE to my theme's name and put it in my template.php. My new file is in the templates directory and called custom-template.tpl. Ive put <?php print theme('custom_template') ?> in various TPL files but nothing happens.

Comment: It should be called "custom-template.tpl.php", not "custom-template.tpl"! Also make sure you clear the caches.

Comment: Thats was a typo, the file is called custom-template.tpl.php. All that ive put in it is <h1>Test</h1>. Ive cleared the cache multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

[Drupal - Render a sub view/partial within template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802422/drupal-render-a-sub-view-partial-within-template)